# Check if a Radio Streaming url is working or not with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, audio-streaming

Hi I'm doing a website which contains several radios. I need to know, through javascript, if a radio stream url is working or not. I achieve this in PHP doing a `file_get_contents($radio_source, false, NULL, -1, 600);`, doing this I know that if the request reached the limit (600) then the request is alive, otherwise, not. My question is: Does exist a way to do this in Javascript?. So far, $.ajax doesn't seems to be an option, because doesn't have any parameter to help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this cool function built for javascript: https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/functions/filesystem/file_get_contents.js .
That uses XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Awesome! Just what I needed the same code in php worked in js as charm!

Comment: is version control. you can check back the history https://github.com/kvz/locutus/blob/458e595f90a82e8d80105c4784defd380222306b/functions/filesystem/file_get_contents.js

Answer (score 0):

You could have the same code that you do in php now, but refer to it with an ajax request.

I know you said no ajax, but I mean referring to the php file, not the radio stream.

Comment: Sorry that's not an option, I don't want to make too many request, If I do that I'll be doing a request to my server and THEN a request to the stream. I just want to make one single request to the stream in order to check if its alive or not.